# If I know how many of a collection to create, should I create them all or create them on the fly by add()

Tags: java, collections

I need to create an array of several hundred objects. `MyObject` has a large memory footprint, takes as bit of effort/time to create and will be created one at a time. I know how many when I start. I can create an array `MyObject[n]` sized appropriately then insert the `MyObject` via an index. Or I can create an `ArrayList<MyObject>` then do an `add(MyObject)`. The code size and structure is similar but I can imagine the second method 'could' fragment the memory differently than the first method. (Really?) I suppose the difference is pretty small, especially considering there are less than 1000 entries, but my guess is that the first method is better as it uses information I have earlier in the process. Does the `ArrayList.add()` have to do extra work to increase its size?

Comment: In both cases you end up with the references in an array, in the `ArrayList` case there may be some extra capacity left in the backing array. Otherwise there's no difference and with so few objects they wouldn't show up anyway.

Comment: First of all, you can tell ArrayList [how many](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList-int-) there will be. Second, yes, `add()` does have to do a little work to increase capacity (not every time it's called, though), but that is trivial and you shouldn't worry about it. Finally, memory fragmentation isn't a concern with the way Java allocates memory. So it doesn't matter which way you choose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the implementation of `add(E e)` inside the class `ArrayList`, you can see this:

```
public boolean add(E e) {
    modCount++;
    add(e, elementData, size); //check below
    return true;
}

private void add(E e, Object[] elementData, int s) {
    if (s == elementData.length)
        elementData = grow();
    elementData[s] = e;
    size = s + 1;
}
```

So basically, the only time when `ArrayList.add()` does something more than simply setting an element inside the `E[]` array that it holds, is when `s == elementData.length`.

If you check what these fields are:

- `elementData`: "The array buffer into which the elements of the ArrayList are stored. The capacity of the ArrayList is the length of this array buffer"
- `size`: "The size of the ArrayList (the number of elements it contains)."

So, if you check the constructor `public ArrayList(int initialCapacity)`, you can see that when you provide an initial capacity, the array `elementData` will be initialized with the capacity you provide:

```
if (initialCapacity > 0) {
    this.elementData = new Object[initialCapacity];
```

Which, in other words, means that the `if (s == elementData.length)` condition will never be met if you know in advance the number of elements that you will store in the array, and so the `elementData = grow()` will never be called making the usage of `.add()` method basically equivalent to you manually setting each element inside the array by index.

To sum up, if you know that you will store `850` elements in your list, then doing this:

```
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>(850);
elements.add(element1);
elements.add(element2);
//...
elements.add(element850);
```

... is practically equivalent, operations-wise, than doing the set into an array yourself (there is one if-check and one increment more but that's really irrelevant). With the advantage though that you have a structure such as `List` that makes the object much easier to use (you'll be able to use iterators and all other features provided by `List` interface).

So especially when the number of elements is so small (< 1000) and that you know how many they are in advance, I wouldn't overthink it and go directly into an `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank you Matteo.  As it turns out, there may be tens of thousands of entries, but still less than a million, so your argument holds.  I didn't look close enough at the API to see the constructor with the `initialCapacity`, which should have answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

`elementData = grow()` is super crucial. `ArrayList` uses the double-and-copy strategy to amortize the cost of insertion. When it hit's the length of it's internal buffer it creates a new array of double the size of the last and copies in the old data. So, `add(x)` amortizes to `O(1)` (constant) because over the course of enough `add`s, it averages to a constant insertion time.

I mean, think about this logically:

1. Why on earth offer an `initialSize` in the constructor if it's of no consequence?
2. How can it continue to just accept data and behave like an array?

But, he is right: unless you're working with a huge list and perpetually updating it, its of no consequential effect